# How do I solve this quadratic inequality with fractions?

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I'm a little confused with quadratic inequalities? Can someone explain how do I work out the final exam? I can do the factorising, etc but I'm not too sure how to determine ALL values of x.

eg.

$\frac{x+4} {2x-4} ≤ x - 2$

Doing the simplifying if $ x > 0$

I end up with

$0 ≤ (x-4)(2x -1)$

so, points of interest are:

$x = 1/2 $

$x = 4 $

How do I work out all values that $x$ is pointing to?
I tried testing points right of the $x=4$ on the number line.

eg. $x = 5$

$ 0 ≤ (5-4)(2(5) -1)$

ie. $0 < 9$

so - it looks like its true $x > 4$

Test left of $1/2$:

$ 0 ≤ (0-4)(0-1) $

ie. $ 0 < 4$

so, its true again.
What I don't understand why we perform the testing step? Is it to test if the region is actually matching the inequality?

Also, what's the best method to find ALL values of x?

Comment: You have three cases: (a) $x>2$ so $2x-4>0$ and you can multiply the inequality as you did and it does not change. (b) $x=2$ and the LHS is not even defined. (c) $x<2$ so $2x-4<0$ and you can still multiply the inequality by $2x-4$ but the inequality *reverses* i.e. $\le$ turns into $\ge$. I would do those three cases separately and then join up the sets of solutions.

Comment: Hey - one of the roots is 1/2. A 1/2 is neither odd or even, so how would you do it with wavy method? just checking, the line passes from +ve to -ve for 4, then -ve till 2, -ve, till 1/2, and then +ve after 1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the ***Wavy Curve Method***:

It involves the following steps:

1. Make RHS $0$.
2. Factor the polynomials.
3. Make the coefficient of the variable of all factors positive.
4. Multiply/divide both sides of the inequality by $-1$ to remove the '$-$' sign.
5. Find the roots and asymptotes of the inequality by equating each factor to $0$.
6. Plot the points on a number line and start with the largest factor. Here the curve from the positive region of the number line should intersect that point. Now look at the power of that factor and if it's odd, then we have to change the path of the curve from their respective roots while if it's even continue in the same region.

Here's how it will be in your case:

$$\frac{x+4}{2x-4}\leq x-2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x+4}{2(x-2)}-(x-2)\leq0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x+4-2(x-2)^2}{2(x-2)}\leq0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x+4-2x^2-8+8x}{2(x-2)}\leq0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{-2x^2+9x-4}{2(x-2)}\leq0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2x^2-9x+4}{x-2}\geq0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2(x-4)(x-\frac12)}{x-2}\geq0$$
So, after factorizing, we have the roots/critical points as $4,0.5$ and $2$.
Onto step $6$:

[image: WC]

Since we are interested in the solutions where $f(x)\geq0$ so, that'd be the region with the '$+$' sign.
$$\text{Thus, }\bf x\in \left[\frac12,2\right)\cup[4,∞) $$ 
Note that we don't include 2 in the solution as for that value the function wouldn't be defined.

If you're interested in knowing more about the **Wavy Curve Method** then check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKRYf4UemaI) to know its application and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HwFttjpeuA) to know the logic behind this method.

Answer (score 1):

You have$$\frac{x+4}{2x-4}\leqslant x-2\iff\frac{-2x^2+9x-4}{2(x-2)}\leqslant0.\tag1\label A$$Note that the roots of the numerator are $\frac12$ and $4$ and that therefore the numerator is greater than or equal to $0$ in $\left[\frac12,4\right]$ and it is smaller than or equal to $0$ in $\left(-\infty,\frac12\right]\cup[4,\infty)$. On the other hand, the denominator is greater than $0$ on $(2,\infty)$ and smallar than $0$ on $(-\infty,2)$. Therefore, the RHS of $\eqref A$ holds if and only if$$x\in\left[\frac12,2\right)\cup[4,\infty).$$

Comment: I’d like to suggest [Wavy Curve Method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/) to the OP to visualise the intervals faster.

Comment: @insipidintegrator hey, how would find the value of 2 in the wavy method?

Comment: @Chris $2$ is the zero of the denominator. You must track how both the numerator and the denominator change the sign.

Comment: erm - how does that work if one of the roots is 1/2? its neither odd or even?

Comment: No! The oddness/evenness (also called *parity*) of the POWER of the $(x-a)$ term must be seen. Here all the powers are equal to $1$, which is odd.